# Git keeps obsolete files

Tags: git, azure-devops

Since a few days I'm running into troubles when using git on Windows:

```
git version 2.36.2.windows.1
```

Together with Microsoft Azure DevOps Server 2019.

Whenever I pull or merge, sometimes, it keeps the obsolete/ older file. It looks like git is not only checking the hash, but also somehow the timestamp and it got messed up. I then have a clean working tree, but the file on the remote looks different than my local copy of the exact same commit hash.

How does it come?

Example:

```
git fetch origin
git checkout test
git pull origin test
```

Then it says: Already up to date. But when I do:

```
git diff --name-only origin test
```

Then I get hell of a lot of files that differ..

Answer (score 0):

Check first f this is related to eol (end of lines) issue.

```bash
cd C:\path\to\repository
git config --global core.autocrlf false
git add --renormaize -- .
git status
```

Check if the status still show modified files once you disable any automatic eol processing.
[Using `.gitattributes`](https://www.edwardthomson.com/blog/advent_day_1_gitattributes_for_text_files.html) is a better practice.